# How to write vector of ostreams in C++ which takes in all the different output streams like cout, ostringstream and ofstream

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, ostream

I am trying to implement a logger which can be registered with multiple streams like ostringstream, ofstream etc. I tried to implement the function like this

```
void register_stream(std::ostream& a);
```

The vector is as follows

```
std::vector<std::ostream> streams;
```

The register stream and operator overloading is as follows

```
void logger::register_stream(std::ostream &a)`

{

    streams.push_back(a);

}

template <typename T>

void logger::operator<<(T const& value)

{

    for (auto stream : streams)

    {

        (stream) << value;

    }

}
```

I am trying to implement a logger to write to all registered streams on a single operator "`<<`" call.

The following is the invocation code:

```
std::ostringstream os;
    std::ofstream f;
    logger l;
    l.register_stream(f);
    l.register_stream(os);
    l << "log this";
```

I am getting an error:

> C2280: `std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::basic_ostream(const std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &)`: attempting to reference a deleted function

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Store `ostream*` pointers, as in `std::vector<std::ostream*> streams;`. You are trying to store them by value, but stream objects cannot be copied.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That would bring in lifetime issues.  They'd have to make sure the logger doesn't outlive the streams.

Comment: Could you clarify that via code. I am new to C++. Sorry.

Comment: @NathanOliver Well, yes. They would have to make sure of that no matter the design. It's kinda pointless to have a logger trying to write to streams that are already dead.

Comment: @NathanOliver The requirement that it supports `std::cout` throws out any solution that would manage lifetime for all elements. It implies that lifetime concerns must be managed separately, perhaps by using a wrapper that *conditionally* manages lifetime.

Comment: Change three lines. One I've already shown. Then `streams.push_back(&a);` (note the ampersand). Finally `(*stream) << value;` (note the star).

Comment: You need to resolve your ownership issues. If the list is going to own and destroy the streams then you could make it a vector of unique_ptr to stream. The problem with that is that by design streams aren't properly virtual, so if you have different kinds of streams (file streams stderr streams, etc, you would also need to know how to destroy (or not bother) each one. I guess you could bind each stream with a destruction method based on its true type, and store that in the list.

Comment: The life time of the stream and the logger would be maintained in the desturctor of the class calling the logger. Would this design resolve the issue ?. I am new to C++ and has Java background. I'm really finding it hard get a grip on the language. But thanks a ton to all of you for shedding some light on this. I would have to probably go through google alot just to comprehend what you guys are discussing :)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Don't answer in comments please

Comment: logger::~logger()
{
 string_stream << std::endl;
 for (auto stream : streams)
 {
  (*stream) << string_stream.str().c_str();
 }
}

is giving me the exception

Exception thrown at 0x5295D901 (msvcp140d.dll) in Logger.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xDDDDDDDD. occurred

This is the invocation code:
l.register_stream(f);
 l.register_stream(os);
 l.register_stream(std::cout);
 l << "jhii" << 9;
 l << "asdasdasd";
 // std::cout << os.str();
 l.~logger();
 f.flush();
 f.close();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't store copies of your streams, they are not copiable. You have to store [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)s or pointers instead.

```
class logger {
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::ostream>> streams;
public:
    void register_stream(std::ostream &stream) {
        streams.emplace_back(stream);
    }

    template <typename T>
    void operator<<(T const &value) {
        for (auto &stream : streams) { // note the '&'
            stream.get() << value;
        }
    }
};
```

or if you want to be able to chain your calls like `l << "log" << " this";`:

```
    template <typename T>
    logger & operator<<(T const &value) {
        for (auto &stream : streams) {
            stream.get() << value;
        }
        return *this;
    }
```

Comment: You can just store a pointer, that's what `reference_wrapper` does for you.

Comment: logger::~logger() 
{ string_stream << std::endl; 
for (auto stream : streams) 
{ (*stream) << string_stream.str().c_str(); } } 
is giving me the exception Exception thrown at 0x5295D901 (msvcp140d.dll) in Logger.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xDDDDDDDD. occurred This is the invocation code: 
l.register_stream(f); l.register_stream(os); l.register_stream(std::cout); l << "jhii" << 9; l << "asdasdasd"; // std::cout << os.str(); l.~logger(); f.flush(); f.close();

Comment: @user5856076 Don't call explicitly the destructor of your logger. Also, flush and close are useless, they are called by the destructor of ofstream.

Comment: "You can't store your streams by value, they are not copiable." – That's only true for the polymorphic case. For the statically typed case, both string and file streams are movable since C++11, which is enough for some standard containers (e.g. `vector`), and more than is needed for many others (e.g. `map`, or also `deque` if you only do `emplace_front`/`emplace_back`/`pop_front`/`pop_back` etc.).

Comment: @O’Neil What I’m trying to do is write everytime into a string stream and at destruction of logger write the string  into all the registered streams in logger. The problem however is the logger destructor is called before the class destructor of the class which uses the logger, hence preventing me from controlling when to write to the file ie. flush and close. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5):

`ostream` does both formatting and writing into the underlying `streambuf`. So that when you use `operator<<` multiple times it formats the same input multiple times unnecessarily. A more optimal approach is to format once and then copy the formatted output to the multiple underlying `stream`s using unformatted output function [`ostream::write`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write).

It is convenient to have `std::ostream` interface so that you can pass it to existing functions expecting `std::ostream` interface.

You basically need a custom `streambuf` implementation. Writing one from scratch is good learning experience but tedious and error prone because [`streambuf` interface](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) is somewhat hard to comprehend and implement correctly. Use [The Boost Iostreams Library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) instead.

Working example:

```
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct MultiSink {
    using char_type = char;

    struct category
        : boost::iostreams::sink_tag
        , boost::iostreams::flushable_tag
    {};

    std::vector<std::ostream*> sinks_;

    std::streamsize write(char const* s, std::streamsize n) {
        for(auto sink : sinks_)
            sink->write(s, n);
        return n;
    }

    bool flush() {
        for(auto sink : sinks_)
            sink->flush();
        return true;
    }

    void add_sink(std::ostream& s) {
        sinks_.push_back(&s);
    }

    void remove_sink(std::ostream& s) {
        sinks_.erase(std::remove(sinks_.begin(), sinks_.end(), &s), sinks_.end());
    }
};

int main() {
    MultiSink sink;
    boost::iostreams::stream<MultiSink> stream(sink);
    stream->add_sink(std::cout);
    stream->add_sink(std::cerr);

    stream << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
}
```

Note that the code assumes that the registered streams outlive the multi-sink. If that is not the case you need to unregister the streams from the multi-sink before they get destroyed.

Comment: Good idea to go for the buffers. Just thinking through the disadvantages: I can see an argument that says that each stream could have different formatters: it could certainly be in a different width/radix state; and so the output could be (intentionally) different. You could drive different bandwidth logging streams using custom severity manipulators. However I can also see an argument that says you wouldn't want accidentally different output in the different streams, and the manipulator stuff could be implemented by this stream manager, anyway.

Comment: I have a limitation of using only standard i/o libraries.Correct me if I'm wrong but boost would violate that restriction right ?
Thank you so much for you help :)

Comment: @user5856076 The boost components used here are header-only, you do not need to link extra static/shared libraries here.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few conceptual issues to disentangle:

1. `std::cout` is a global object, but `std::ostringstream` and `std::ofstream` are *types*. Discussing them as interchangeable outputs is a category error
2. `std::cout` is a global object with program lifetime, but any `std::ofstream` *instance* you create may have different lifetime. You need some way to tell whether its lifetime could end *before* your logger (which isn't a worry with `cout`, unless your logger also has program lifetime), or to let the logger know that *it* is responsible for your stream's lifetime.
3. having a `std::vector<std::ostream> streams` cannot work, because:

   1. it copies the streams by value, which is explicitly prohibited (see the deleted copy constructor [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/basic_ostream))
   2. even if it was allowed, it would be broken because of [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+object+slicing).

With those out of the way, Maxim's answer is good but doesn't address stream lifetimes - if those aren't a problem (you're happy to statically guarantee every registered stream will outlive the logger), then it's a good solution.

If you *do* need some extra support to manage object lifetimes, you require something a bit more elaborate - eg. storing proxy objects that know whether or not the logger owns a given stream.

Comment: Once again, *copying* is no longer required for `std::vector`, ever since C++11, (assuming that one remembers to `insert` or `push_back` *rvalues*). Slicing is indeed a big problem, though, that's also why the stream base classes have a `protected` move c'tor. (You can, e.g. make a `std::vector<std::ostringstream>` though.)

Answer (score 0):

"If you do need some extra support to manage object lifetimes, you require something a bit more elaborate - eg. storing proxy objects that know whether or not the logger owns a given stream." – Useless

The current solution to this problem in my current project looks much like this:

```
using ostream_deleter = std::function<void(std::ostream *)>;
using ostream_ptr = std::unique_ptr<std::ostream, ostream_deleter>;
```

This allows you to store a new stream object, with ownership, e.g.

```
ostream_deleter d{std::default_delete<std::ostream>{}};
ostream_ptr fileStream{new std::ofstream{"/tmp/example.foo"}, std::move(d)};
```

Note that you should create the type-erased deleter first for reasons of exception safety.

It also allows you to use global streams which are known to outlive your logger:

```
ostream_ptr coutStream{&std::cout, [](std::ostream &) {}};
```

There is also a [`null_deleter` in Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/null_deleter.html) if you want more of a self-documenting syntax.

Unfortunately, there's still an issue with streams that may be internally *redirected*. Indeed, C++ supports redirecting the output to (or input from) any stream to a different stream buffer, e.g.

```
std::ofstream logStream{"/tmp/my.log"};
const auto oldBuf = std::cout.rdbuf(logStream.rdbuf());
std::cout << "Hello World.\n"; // output redirected to /tmp/my.log
std::cout.rdbuf(oldBuf); // undo redirection
```

The issue here is that the lifetime of the stream buffer is tied to `logStream`, not `std::cout`. This complicates any lifetime management rsp. makes a fully general solution about impossible. Discipline and convention should still help a lot, of course, and admittedly stream redirection is a fairly obscure and rarely used feature.